# using background image for li

Tags: css

I'm using a background image for a `<li>` that will be used as a button, but it's not fully shown; however, when write text then it shows.
I don't want text to be written it's already printed on background image. I am unable to set a width - how can I fix this?

```
#footernav li#footerlocation
{
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-image: url(../images/ourlocation.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is in setting display to inline.  If you want background and width, but you also need an inline-type list, set float: left.

Comment: Thanks, but somewhere i saw they indent the text to thousand pixel to disappear, anyway i follow ur sugestion and its working now.

Comment: You can still indent the text -- that actually has nothing to do with the layout.  The problem is that when you set display to inline on a block-level element, it will naturally shrink to the minimum width required; so if an element has no text, the width goes to zero.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the following example:

```
   ul#footernav li { 
        display:inline; 
        }
    ul#footernav li a{ 
        display:block; 
        width:155px;
        text-indent:-9999px;
        }
    ul#footernav li.footerlocation a{ 
        height:30px ; 
        background: url('images/image.jpg') bottom left no-repeat; 
        }
    ul#footernav li.footerlocation a:hover{ 
        height:30px ; 
        background: url(images/image.jpg) top left no-repeat; 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks SuperUnititled that's what i want to do that time, next time will must use this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes i have the same problem, i just removed css style `display: inline` and add `display: list-item; float:left;` my problem solved, hope this helps.

Thanks, Sankar B

Answer (score 0):

set the width and height for the image

Answer (score 0):

May be help in this

```
.tab-content ul li{display: block;padding-left: 30px;background-image:url('images/blue-icon.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: 0 2px;margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

We can simply add the following css rule:

```
ul.check-list{  
    list-style-image: url(images/tick.jpg);
}
```